# Elementary way to compute Hodge numbers of Grassmanian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

I know that by using Hodge decomposition and the fact that Schubert cells are Hodge cycles you can compute the Hodge numbers of Grassmanian but is there a more elementary way to compute sheaf cohomology $H^i(\Omega_{Gr(m,n)}^j$)?

Comment: Whether it is more elementary depends on one's taste I guess, but the cotangent bundle $\Omega_{\mathrm{Gr}(m,n)}^1$ is completely reducible as an equivariant vector bundle (the Grassmannian is cominuscule), and hence so are its exterior powers. One can apply Borel-Weil-Bott to compute the sheaf cohomology of all of the summands that appear, and get the Hodge numbers in this way.

Comment: Are you aware that $h^{p,q}=0$ for $p\neq q$? Therefore $h^{p,p}=b_{2p}$, and the computation of the Betti numbers is well-known.

Comment: There's an arithmetic approach which is elementary to implement (but depends on hard theorems). You could calculate $\#Gr(m,n)(\mathbf{F}_q)$ as a function of $q$. The answer will be a polynomial in $q$. This implies that $h^{i,j} = 0$ for $i \neq j$, and moreover tells you what $h^{n,n} = b_{2n}$ will be by the Weil conjectures.

Comment: @abx I know the numbets but why $h^{p,q}=0$ is there an elementry proof for this ?i already mentioned the proof by the hodge theory in my post I want a proof withoat using hodge theory

Comment: @pbelmans ,anonymous thanks these methods are very interesting but they are even more advanced than the proof by hodge theory

Comment: The point is that the Grassmannian admits a "cellular decomposition", i.e. a filtration $X\supset X_1\supset \ldots $ where each $X_i\smallsetminus X_{i+1}$ is a disjoint union of affine spaces. It is not hard then to prove that all cohomology classes are algebraic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the ways is to use the projective bundle theorem that says that if $X = \mathbb{P}_Y(E)$ is a projectivization of a rank $r$ vector bundle $E$ over $Y$ then
$$
H^\bullet(X) = H^\bullet(Y) \oplus H^\bullet(Y)[-2] \oplus \dots \oplus H^\bullet(Y)[2-2r],
$$
where $[s]$ stands for the shift of grading.

Now consider the partial flag variety with the natural projection
$$
p \colon Fl(1,2,\dots,k;n) \to Gr(k,n).
$$
On the one hand, $Fl(1,2,\dots,k;n)$ has a structure of an iterated projective bundle, hence all of its cohomology is of $(p,p)$-type, and its generating function is
$$
h_{Fl}(t) = (1+t+\dots+t^{n-1})(1+t+\dots+t^{n-2})\cdots(1+t+\dots+t^{n-k}).
$$
On the other hand, the map $p$ is also an iterated projective bundle, hence $H^\bullet(Gr(k,n))$ is a direct summand of $H^\bullet(Fl(1,2,\dots,k;n))$, hence it is also of $(p,p)$-type, and moreover its generating function is
$$
h_{Gr}(t) = \frac{h_{Fl}(t)}{(1+t)(1+t+t^2)\cdots(1+t+ \dots+t^{k-1})}.
$$